# Use capital letters as input for pygame controls

Tags: rotation, keyboard, controls, pygame, keypress

I have the following key setup for pygame drawing rotation around the x axis:

```
while done == False:
# ALL EVENT PROCESSING SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
         done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
        # User pressed down on a key
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

 #X rotation clockwise
 if keys[pygame.K_x]:
 #rotate around the x axis
    angle_y = angle_y+.1

 if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT:
    #X rotation counterclockwise
    if key[pygame.K_x]:
      angle_y = angle_y+.1
```

I want to hold down the x key and my image will rotate clockwise around the x axis
I then want to hold down left shift and the x key (or capital X) and have the image rotate counterclockwise.

with my current setup it is only moving in the direction of clockwise even when I hold down shift.

Comment: Format your code - make correct indentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `angle_y = angle_y+.1` in both situation - **PLUS**

(your code isn't formated)

I think you also need change code to this:

```
if keys[pygame.K_x]:
   if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT:
      #X rotation counterclockwise
      angle_y = angle_y-.1
   else:
      #X rotation clockwise
      angle_y = angle_y+.1
```

In your version if you press `left_shift + x` both `if` are true

`if keys[pygame.K_x]:` is True

`if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT: if key[pygame.K_x]:` is True